# How do I get the overall percentage of a given value in a data set

Tags: r, function

I am really new at R and this is probably a really basic question. I have a data set with 9 columns that have information on income data. How do I find the overall percentage of individuals who earn more than 50k?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I definitely think we can help you with this problem. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example, which explains how to make a great reproducible example with a minimal dataset

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to help if you provide some sample data in a reproducible format.

Let's say this is your data

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5, income = c(55000, 12000, 650000, 100000, 32000))
df

#  id income
#1  1  55000
#2  2  12000
#3  3 650000
#4  4 100000
#5  5  32000
```

To count the percentage of people whose income is greater than 50K, you can count the number of people whose income is greater than 50k and divide it by total number of people which can be done as -

```
perc <- sum(df$income > 50000)/nrow(df) * 100
perc
#[1] 60
```

Another shorter way to do the same thing in R would be to consider logical values as numbers. So `TRUE -> 1` and `FALSE -> 0` so to get the percentage we can do -

```
perc <- mean(df$income > 50000)  * 100
perc
#[1] 60
```

Comment: Thank you. I t was very helpful and easy